# Incompatibilities of cmap with fontenc/hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, incompatibility, copy-paste, font-encodings

The following code doesn't compile (with `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdfa=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

unless I omit either the `fontenc`-line or the `pdfa=true`-option from the `hyperref`-line. The error message I get says: `! pdfTeX error (setup): \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file.` Is there something I can do or is this an incompatibility?

Comment: Your MWE runs if you do not use `cmap` or without `fontenc` you said. The option `pdfa=true` is not documented jet so I would prefer not to use it. You can change your document later to pdf/a if you need. `\pdfminorversion` defines the pdf versionnummer you will be allowed to include in your document.

Comment: The error does not appear in TeXlive 2018.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fatal error you get is

```
! pdfTeX error (setup): \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after data is writte
n to the PDF file.
<to be read again> 
                   \edef 
l.6 \begin{document}
```

Using `\tracingall`, this can be tracked down a bit more to the `\AtBeginDocument` hook. What it looks like is that `hyperref` wants to set some PDF settings at the start of the document when given the `pdfa=true` option. Normally, nothing will have been written to the PDF at that stage, so all is fine, but `cmap` has already written to the PDF so breaks this. The solution is to load `cmap` after `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdfa=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cmap}
\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiling your MWE I get the warning: `Package cmap Warning: fontenc already loaded - some fonts may be unprocessed.` You too?

Answer (score 20):

**Summary**
The correct answer is indeed the solution of Gernsheim with

```
\RequirePackage{pdf14}
```

right at the beginning before `\documentclass`.

**Details**

The minor version of the PDF file is set by `\pdfminorversion` in pdfTeX
(Older versions are using `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion`). The version number is
written in the very beginning of the PDF file:

```
%!PDF-1.4
```

The objects are following afterwards. If pdfTeX has written objects, it
had to start the PDF file with the PDF header and its version number.
At this time the version number is fixed.

Theoretically pdfTeX could be extended to go back in the file and replace the
minor version byte by an updated version number. However, keep in mind, what
the purpose of the PDF version number is. It tells what features are supported
and which features are not in the scope of the particular PDF version.
For instance, we would have a problem if the version is first set to a high value.
A packages detects this and thinks, hurray I can use advanced PDF stuff,
and then another package says, April, April, we want to have 1.4 because of PDF/A.

Therefore it is correct if pdfTeX complains with an error that the version
setting is too late.

The package `cmap` should be loaded at an early stage, before fonts are loaded.
Because it hacks into this machinery to add its Unicode mappings to the fonts.
By `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` new fonts are loaded and the object for the
mapping T1 to Unicode is written to the PDF file. Afterwards it is too late
for changing the version number of the PDF file.

Package `hyperref` usually needs to be loaded later. At this stage it cannot
change the version number anymore.

**Solutions**

At TeX macro level the PDF version number should be set at early as possible.
This is done by package `pdf14` (it could be extended to support older pdfTeX
versions). A document class can already load other packages like `cmap` and
even `hyperref`, therefore the packages needs to be loaded even earlier in
the general case. LaTeX does not allow `\usepackage` before `\documentclass`,
but `\RequirePackage` works:

```
\RequirePackage{pdf14}
\documentclass{...}
```

An alternative method is used by `ps2pdf` of Ghostscript. It has companions
`ps2pdf12`, `ps2pdf13`, `ps2pdf14`, … that contain an explicite setting
of the version number for PDF.

In the TeX world this can be achieved by generating a new format `pdflatex14`
that uses `\pdfminorversion=4` instead of `\pdfminorversion=5`.

**Homework for `hyperref`**

Using `\pdflastobj` and friends it is possible to detect, if something
has already been written to the PDF file. Therefore I will extend `hyperref`
in version 2012/12/30 v6.82w and add some sanity checks before the version
number is changed.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! User JosephWright's solution works for me, so I'll keep it as the chosen answer for now for its simplicity (unless there are other issues with it). User Gernsheim's original answer didn't provide enough context for me to understand why, though your explanation is great. Btw, there is another completely different thing I wrote about [elsewhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59359/certain-hyperlinks-memoirhyperref-placed-too-low), I hope you don't mind me drawing your attention to this.

Comment: The spirit of this answer is right, and it helped me find my related problem. Someone added `\pdfoptionpdfminorversion 6` after a bunch of `\usepackage{}` calls. I moved it to be right after `\documentclass{}`.

Comment: For me, this was the key: "The package cmap should be loaded at an early stage,". I brought it to the beginning of the list, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 14):

Putting a

```
\RequirePackage{pdf14}
```

in the preamble, just before the

```
\documentclass
```

worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Perhaps someone else can help with identifying the reason for the original incompatibility.

Answer (score 3):

The issue does not appear on TeXlive 2018 anymore.

I could reproduce it somehow, when using the `pdfx` package: To make archival PDFs, one should use the [pdfx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfx) package. In case `cmap` is loaded, one has to load the `pdfx` package **before** `fontenc`. `hyperref` is loaded internally by the `pdfx` package.

In case one of these three packages (cmap, pdfx, fontenc) is not loaded, the error disappears. When loading all of them, the ordering has to be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

(Solution found out by trial and error). Note that `fontenc` might not be necessary in plain US texts without diatrics. See [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc/677#677).