LaTeX PDF error with leaflet and tcolorbox
I get the following error when printing the PDF, when using the leaflet documentclass and tcolorbox. 
The following (minimal) working example is used as reference.
\documentclass[notumble,letterpaper,foldmark]{leaflet}
\title{MWE on Weird Error\\[1cm] \includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{SomeLogo.jpg}}
\author{Please Help}
\def\docdate{August 05, 2024} % change as needed.
\date{Last updated~\docdate\\printed \today}


\renewcommand*\foldmarkrule{.3mm}
\renewcommand*\foldmarklength{0mm}
\CutLine*{1}%   Dotted line without scissors (same as \CutLine*[.]{1})
\CutLine[-]{6}% Solid line with scissors

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\usepackage[breakable,most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{infobox}[2][]
{breakable,enhanced,
  colframe = grey!25,
  colback  = grey!10,
  coltitle = grey!20!black, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  %interior style={left color = blue!30, right color = blue!10},
  %title style = {left color =blue!10, right color = blue!40},
  title    = #2,
  #1,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
%Front cover: Looking for something similar on the front, except with the updated NAVMAC logo.
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[2-3]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[4-5]
\begin{itemize}
\item Item One
\item Item Two
\item \lipsum[1]
\item Item Four
\end{itemize}

\section{Section 4}
Added text to make the \texttt{tcolorbox} split over pages.
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item Green Eggs and Ham
\item I am Sam, will not eat green eggs and ham.
\item So say I am.
\end{itemize}

\section{Adding Features}
\begin{infobox}{A Text Color Box\hfill\faComment}
This is an example of a Text Color Box. Notice that we used the open source Font Awesome icon for Anchor.
This \texttt{tcolorbox} was declared in the preamble as a \texttt{infobox}. You can define your own boxes, with different colors and behaviors, as you see fit.
Notice that these boxes can spill over from one page to the next, since we use the \texttt{breakable} option.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item Also note, that you can put stuff inside a \texttt{tcolorbox}
\item Here is a list.
\item It's a story
\item About a lovely lady
\item Who was bring up three very lovely girls.
\end{itemize}
\end{infobox}

Here is a bulleted list. Those are easy to typeset.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item Space, the final frontier.
\item These are the voyages of the Starship \emph{Enterprise}
\item A Long Time Ago,
\item In a Galaxy far, far away\ldots
\end{itemize}

If you like, we can add equations. For example, if $ax^2 + bx +c =0$ and $a\ne0$, then:
$$x= \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} $$

\begin{infobox}{Contact Information}
\begin{tabular}{l p{.75\textwidth}}
\faHome & My Cookie Company\\
& 5555 Main Street\\
& Any Town, US 12345\\
\faPhone & \href{tel:5556667777}{555-666-7777}\\
\texttt{FAX} & 555-1212\\
\faLink & \burl{https://www.cookiecompany.com/longurl/main/orderForm.aspx}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{infobox}

\end{document}

How do I correct this?

an example that uses a local image can not be tested and is not a sensible example. Try if it works if you add \DocumentMetadata{} before \documentclass.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you! Adding that single line works.
Sorry for not making a truly MWE with the reference to the image. Any jpg would be fine. I just sanitized the document.
Before I mark this as a solution, any reason why there would be this weird error, what caused it, a link as to what \DocumentMetadata{} does, and any other related items that might help in the future?

I'd be curious to know how you created the original PDF without generating at least warnings regarding incompatibilities, if not errors. any method I try results in at least warnings, but otherwise errors. (after replacing the image obviously.)

@cfr I used pdflatex to compile, and the TeX Live 2024. In searching for the error, there were some mention of the xcolor package conflicting. From trial and error, I think I narrowed it down to this documentclass (leaflet) and the tcolorbox package.

The warnings I get from TeXworks are:
breakurl.sty
Package breakurl Warning: You are using breakurl while processing via pdflatex.
mwe_leaf_tcb_col.tex
96
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 96--97
[][]$\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 https : / / www . cookiecompany .
mwe_leaf_tcb_col.tex
96
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 96--97
\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 com / longurl / main /

using breakurl is pointless as the full warning message tells you. this isn't the cause of the problem, but ignoring warnings usually means trouble of some kind at some point. (in this case, the package detects the problem and renders itself null and void, so loading it should merely be pointless, but that's often not the case.)

Your pdf is missing the ExtGState resource. That happens sometimes with pgf if some package plays around with the shipout.
\DocumentMetadata loads the LaTeX pdfmanagement and that handles the adding of the resource in a safer way. For more details see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686905/2388
