# gnuplot to pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot

I produce my graph with gnuplot and then pdflatex. I always used this header that has alwasy worked

```
set terminal epslatex standalone color size 4.0in,3.0in background rgb "white"
set output 'plot.tex'
```

Unfortunately after having run

```
gnuplot plot.gnu && pdflatex plot.tex
```

I got the following error

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./pm-inc-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
```

Any idea how to solve it?

I also run the gnuplot test and the results differs fromt the one posted in this thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412382/gnuplot-line-types](http://thread). It seems I don't have any kind of linetype

[image]

Comment: Did you Google the message? Sends you to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52317/3929, shouldn't be hard to adapt to your case

Comment: I saw that thread. The problem is it gives only a manual solution by adding to the tex file "\pdfminorversion=6". This is very uncomfortable because everytime you recreate the .tex file you need to add that line manually.

Comment: Then have your gnuplot generate pdf 1.5 and not 1.7

Comment: Or rephrase your question to reflect this, it us not at all clear that this is what you're after

Comment: The final .pdf created is in verison 1.5, the intermediate one in 1.7. Anyway the results is not what I want because of the warning message and it seems some features are turned off.

Comment: Then as mentioned reqhrase your question as it is not clear at all what you want.

Comment: What I would like is to avoid the warning. I have never had problem with this procedure. I just recently formatted my computer and now I cannot focus what is going wrong.

Comment: you could  (although possibly not advisable) change your texlive site default to 1.7. Presumably an updated gnuplot has started specifying its output as 1.7 (latex hasn't changed here for some years)